# Template parameter "function type" and "function pointer". When to apply what?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to understand the difference between a "Function Type" and a "Function Pointer" as template parameter and when to apply what. Or, what's the difference?

Simple example:

```
template <int Function(int)>
struct S1 {
    //....
};
template <int (*Function)(int)>
struct S2 {
    //....
};

int always42(int) {
    return 42;
}

int main() {

    S1<always42> s1;
    S2<always42> s2;
    //....
    return 0;
}
```

Or will the "function type" decay to a "function pointer"?

Can somebody please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, function type is adjusted to function pointer for [non-type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter).

> Array and function types may be written in a template declaration, but they are automatically replaced by pointer to object and pointer to function as appropriate.

[[temp.param]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#10)

> A non-type template-parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be of type “pointer to T”.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link and quote. And sorry for being blind . . .  +1

Answer (score 2):

Both template parameters are `int (*)(int)` as there is type decay for `int(int)`. That is, the type of a *non-type template parameter* specified as `int(int)` decays into `int(*)(int)`.

You can see that both template parameters correspond to the same type by using the incomplete `type_shower` class template below:

```
template<typename> struct type_shower;

template <int Function(int)>
struct S1 {
   type_shower<decltype(Function)> _;
};

template <int (*Function)(int)>
struct S2 {
   type_shower<decltype(Function)> _;
};
```

For both, the compiler issues the same error message, which shows the type of `Function`:

> `error: implicit instantiation of undefined template` **`'type_shower<int (*)(int)>'`** `type_shower<decltype(Function)> _;`

---

Note that no type decay occurs if the template parameter is specified as a reference to a function, i.e., `int(&)(int)`:

```
template <int (&Function)(int)>
struct S3 {
   type_shower<decltype(Function)> _;
};
```

> `error: implicit instantiation of undefined template` **`'type_shower<int (&)(int)>'`** `type_shower<decltype(Function)> _;`

---

Comment: Your "type shower" approach is very good. Let the compiler give the evidence via an error message. Really good. I did not fully understand your last edit regarding the reference type. There is no "function-type" that could decay. It is already a "reference to a function". Or did you want to say, the "reference to function" will not decay to a "pointer to function". Then I understand.  Anyway +1

Comment: Your second interpretation: if the type specified for a non-type template parameter is a reference, it doesn't decay into a pointer.